# Rails: How can I ignore fixtures for single test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have two tests. The results of each depend upon the user count.

At the moment, I have no user fixtures. The second test introduces a user in its setup method. The first test would fail if there were users in the db.

But I want to introduce users in users.yml. As such, the first test will fail because of the existing users. Is there any way I can instruct this test to ignore `fixtures/users.yml`?

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTestWithoutExistingUsers < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "Signup page is accessible" do
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_response :success
  end
end

class UsersSignupTestWithExistingUsers < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    post user_registration_path, params: {user: {
      email:                 "user@test.com",
      password:              "password",
      password_confirmation: "password"
    }}
  end

  test "Signup page will redirect" do
    get new_user_registration_path
    assert_response :redirect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test that requires no users in the DB you can stub the method that looks in the DB for users so that it returns an empty set for that test.